# In Minecraft 1.16 I can’t figure out how to check if an entity isn’t in the air

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

This is the command I used which isn’t working:

```
execute as @e[type=husk,tag=remake] run execute at @s unless block ~ ~-1 ~ air run tag @s add looted
```

This command is adding a tag called looted to the entity when they are no longer in the air that is what I want to happen

Comment: how far in the air are you? I'm wondering if one full block below is still maybe another block for some reason. Can't think of anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm missing something pretty obvious but you should just be able to do:

`execute as @e[type=husk,tag=remake] if data entity @s {OnGround:1b} run tag @s add looted`

This adds the tag `looted` to any husk with the tag `remake` if they are not touching the ground

Comment: Could even do `execute as @e[type=husk,tag=remake,nbt={OnGround:1b}] run tag @s add looted`